# Ограничение в 788 пикселей по высоте. Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Ни как не могу выставить высоту больше 788 пикселей для Form в Visual Studio 2019 Community. Если попробовать выставить больше этого значения, то сбрасывается до 788 пикселей. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это старый баг дизайнера WinForms, который вряд ли когда исправят. В дизайнере нельзя задать размер формы больше размера монитора. У вас, очевидно, высота монитора 768 пикселей, плюс размер заголовка и бордюров формы - выходит 788.

Можно задать нужный размер в событии `Form.Load`. Опять же, хотя размер можно указать любой, но реальное значение будет ограничено размером монитора системы, на которой запускается приложение.