# Не меняется размер формы

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Стартовая форма в проекте не дает изменить свой размер по высоте, остановившись на значении в 1100 (нужно 1392) точек. При изменении в свойствах минимальный размер не меняется, добавление значений в код не помогает, как и растягивание формы. При этом остальные формы спокойно достигают нужного размера.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если оставить код, как на скриншоте, и попробовать поменять размеры через свойства формы, то значения в коде меняются на те, что в свойствах

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134439/184217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно это как-то связано с разрешением вашего экрана. WinForms не такой адаптивный в плане визуализации, он очень привязан к текущей системе. Вот, например, я попытался выставить те же значения для свойств, что у вас, но почему-то минимальный размер падает до 726, а сам размер формы падает до 788.
Разрешение моего экрана: 1366x768.
Для своих целей лучше используйте WPF.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключил телевизор с разрешением 1920x1080 к ноутбуку. И вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. В WPF эти же значения выставляются без проблем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробую на другом компьютере проверить, там 2560х1440 разрешение

Comment: `px` - лишнее для xaml, это не css

Comment: @aepot показал для наглядности. Я знаю, что px там по дефолту.

Comment: @vanyavanya так и думал, на 1440 высоте спокойно дал поставить. Но все равно интересно, почему на остальных формах размер проставлялся на 1080 высоте